# Inserting values in libreoffice / excel without using autofill

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I have a libreoffice sheet that I would like to have the rows increase by 1

```
example:
1
2
3
4
```

The problem is I know I can do this with autofill but I have 50000 rows and dragging down takes awhile.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you already have data up to row 50'000, and you have an empty column (I'll use `Col. A`) for the series.

Jump to the last cell in one of the "used" columns <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow down</kbd> (or scroll all the way down to Cell `A50000`) then move sideways to `Col. A` and place an "X" in cell `A50000`. You now have an empty column A, with an "X" in cell `A50000`.

Go to cell `A1` ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> ). Put the number "1" in cell `A1`. Put the following (secret!) formula in cell `A2`:

```
=A1+1
```

Copy cell `A2` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> 
Stay in Cell `A2`...
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow down</kbd>, The area from `A2` to `A50000` should now be highlighted.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste the formula all the way down...

IMPORTANT!
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy the just pasted data (`A2..A50000`).
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste the just copied data "over" the original data with "paste special".

In "Paste Special" make sure that you have **NOT** selected the option: `Formulas`.
This will now paste all the results of the formulas back as fixed numbers.

This should take less than a minute, of which most of it is waiting for the system to calculate and to paste (I tried it for 1 mio lines..)

By just changing the formula from =A1+1 to =A1+2, jou can jump with 2, so 1,3,5,7,... But I assume that you'll use this column as a reference for sorting, so you can always go back to the original order.

Have fun!